# I need to intercept CR0 editing in real mode

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, low-level, real-mode

I need to intercept CR0 editing in real mode and to execute my code before CPU enters in protected mode.
Is it possible and if yes, how I can do this?

Comment: In real mode I don't believe so. In a VM86 task emulating real mode an attempt to switch to protected mode throws an exception that can be caught.

Comment: @Michael, I don't think that's a good idea, but it seems like it's the only way to do that. Thanks.